# Display Word document in a web page using Angular

Tags: html, node.js, angular

I am trying to display a Microsoft Word document in a web page using Angular. But it is only showing the name of the Word document. How can I fix it?

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
<div *ngIf="selectedFile">
<h3>Selected Document: {{ selectedFile.name }}</h3>
<iframe [src]="documentUrl" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; border:              none;"></iframe>
</div>
```

I tried this code, but it is only showing the name of the file selected.